# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named

Tags: python

I've added one folder into my project called `folderb` as follows:

```
mainproject
           foldera
                  __init__.py (empty)
                  filea.py    (module)
           folderb
                  __init__.py (empty)
                  fileb.py    (module)
```

My project is located under:

```
/root/Documents/Repositories/mainproject/
```

Inside `filea.py` module i want to use module's functions of `fileb.py` from `folderb` therefore i import as follows:

```
from folderb.fileb import myfunctionb
```

Nevertheless i am getting this:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'folderb'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: do you have any folders above mainproject?

Comment: mainproject is the python project main folder. I open it in vscode and work on it. In vscode when i do from folderb.fileb import myfunctionb then it's even highlited correctly by the tool.

Comment: @just print out the sys.path (env variable )   and check root path included or not, i think it might spell error

Comment: @JobishJose it prints out me the entire path like /usr/bin/python3.8 /root/Documents/Repositories/mainproject/foldera/filea.py

Comment: This should just work if you **import** `folderb.filea` from a script inside the `mainproject` directory. However, the error you are getting is expected when you would try tro **run** `foldera/filea.py`, because in that case the `folderb` module is not in the Python path. The [Python import system is explained here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and I'm 100% sure this question has been asked and answered many times on SO as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: @wovano u said "because in that case the folderb module is not in the Python path" so how can i add it there so then i can use it in fileA?

Comment: You could add it to the Python path (`sys.path` in Python, or I think PYTHONPATH on the command-line) but it's not the nicest solution. I suspect this is an XY-problem. What are you trying to achieve? Since `foldera` is a Python package, I don't understand why you want to execute the file `foldera/filea.py`. If it's a module, there's generally no need to run/execute it. NB: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/10669875) contains much useful information about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is set up of `sys.path` with two different way of execution of the script. Go to `mainproject` folder. This would work:

```
python -m foldera.filea
```

and this would not

```
python foldera/filea.py
```

You can see why it is so by adding this to beginning of `foldera/filea.py` before any other import:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Invocation using the path will add `/root/Documents/Repositories/mainproject/foldera` to the path where Python interpreter looks for modules. Invocation using the package and module name (with `-m` option) would add `/root/Documents/Repositories/mainproject/`.

You can make the path variant working by augmenting the sys.path, either with

```
PYTHONPATH=. python foldera/filea.py
```

or by adding this ugly code to the beginning of `filea.py`:

```
current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent = os.path.dirname(current)
sys.path.insert(0, parent)
```

Don't do that, use the first option. More information:
[PEP 338 – Executing modules as scripts](https://peps.python.org/pep-0338/)
[Python documentation - Command line and environment, option -m](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)

Comment: i understand but how for instance in my vscode tool or any other to be able to debug if this error happens when trying to debug ? :/

Comment: I don't use vscode, but you should be able to customize what is executed when you press Run or Debug...